# Unable to detect COM wrapped InterOp

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, com

I have a library in `C#`, which i have exposed through `COM` to an unmanaged application in `C++`. On one machine, everything seems to have gone well. The interface is visible, is exposed, and the application is able to view it successfully, and use its functions.

On another machine, however, the `.NET COM InterOp DLL` is simply not visible to the calling application, I cannot debug on that machine so it is not immediately clear where the error is. I get a `COM` exception which indicates that I failed to create the `COM` object.

The `DLL` is present in the `GAC`, and the class is also registered in the `registry`, with the same class `GUID` as I have specified for it.

I have tried moving the assembly to the local folder, but still no detection. The `DLL` is dependent on another assembly which is present with it in the same folder. Moreover, the object creation for the other `DLL`, is dynamic and so it should not affect the object creation for the first assembly.

I might be overlooking a simple, fundamental step, since `COM` is new to me.
What could be the possible reason?

Comment: You might want to check out Microsoft's OLE/COM Object Viewer and ensure that the COM library is registered on the other computer.

Comment: I have checked. I have used regasm to register and unregister the library, then re-register for verification. it is present in the registry, with the same `GUID` which I had specified for the class.

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to troubleshoot this.  You should see your C++ program looking in the registry for the InProcServer32 key to obtain the path to the DLL.  And next it opening the DLL.  And possibly failing next because a dependent DLL could not be found.  One of these operations failed.  Also compare the trace on the good machine.

Comment: OK. I shall try the above. I also used OLE Viewer and I was able to see the type registered.